# Facebook native ads in GridView : MediaView displays a grey rectangle

Tags: android, gridview, facebook-audience-network

I integrated a Facebook native Ad into a GridView. For now, I display test Ads. It works fine except for the one playing a video.

The [MediaView](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/MediaView/) plays a video just fine if the user doesn't interacts with the GridView.
When the GridView is being scrolled, the video is paused and resumed when the Ad reappears on the screen.

**After scrolling the grid up and down** a few times, the **MediaView doesn't show the video anymore** and simply displays a grey rectangle.

Out of curiosity, I tried to run [Ui Automatic Viewer](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/automating-user-interface-testing-on-android--cms-23969) on my device when the MediaView is grey. I noticed something interesting but I can't really make sense of.

In the View hierarchy, I can see the GridView with a some children FrameLayout (container for the Views given by the adapter). This includes the native ad and the other views.

But **when the MediaView is grey**, its FrameLayout **doesn't appear in the View hierarchy** ! But it is rendered just fine on the screen !

I'm very puzzled by what I see.

Also, when I integrated these ads in a RecyclerView, I didn't have this problem (or at least didn't notice it).

Let's talk about the code. I have a reference that points on the Facebook native ad View.

Suggestions welcome :)

Here is the code of the adapter that supplies Views to the GridView :

```
public class AdapterGridGallery extends BaseAdapter implements AdListener {

    private static int POSITION_AD = 4;
    private List<QuizzModel> listQuizzes;

    int heightViews;
    FragmentGallery fragmentGallery;

    View facebookAdView;
    private NativeAd facebookNativeAd;
    private boolean nativeAdSet = false;

    public AdapterGridGallery(FragmentGallery fragment, int height) {
        heightViews = height;
        fragmentGallery = fragment;
        facebookNativeAd = new NativeAd(fragment.getContext(), "my_tag");
        facebookNativeAd.setAdListener(this);
        facebookNativeAd.loadAd();
    }

    public void updateData(List<QuizzModel> list) {
        listQuizzes = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listQuizzes != null ? listQuizzes.size() + 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listQuizzes.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return listQuizzes.get(i).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == POSITION_AD)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View viewQuizz = null;
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                if (facebookAdView == null) {
                    facebookAdView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.view_facebook_native, viewGroup, false);
                    //Settings the height of the view
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams params = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) facebookAdView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = heightViews;
                    params.width = AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                    facebookAdView.setLayoutParams(params);
                }

                viewQuizz = facebookAdView;
                viewQuizz.setTag(0);

                if (facebookNativeAd.isAdLoaded()) {
                    if (!nativeAdSet) {
                        Log.d("NativeAdList", "update views resources");
                        nativeAdSet = true;

                        ImageView nativeAdIcon = (ImageView) facebookAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
                        TextView nativeAdTitle = (TextView) facebookAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
                        TextView nativeAdBody = (TextView) facebookAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
                        MediaView nativeAdMedia = (MediaView) facebookAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
                        TextView nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView) facebookAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
                        Button nativeAdCallToAction = (Button) facebookAdView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);


                        nativeAdSocialContext.setText(facebookNativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
                        nativeAdCallToAction.setText(facebookNativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
                        nativeAdTitle.setText(facebookNativeAd.getAdTitle());
                        nativeAdBody.setText(facebookNativeAd.getAdBody());
                        // Downloading and setting the ad icon.
                        NativeAd.Image adIcon = facebookNativeAd.getAdIcon();
                        NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, nativeAdIcon);
                        // Download and setting the cover image.
                        nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(facebookNativeAd);
                        nativeAdMedia.setAutoplay(true);
                        facebookNativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(facebookAdView);
                        nativeAdCallToAction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("NativeAdList", "views resources already set");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("NativeAdList", "nativeAdCallToAction is set invisible");
                    nativeAdCallToAction.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                view = new CustomView();
            }
            return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of Ui Automator Viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you said

> when I integrated these ads in a RecyclerView, I didn't have this
>   problem (or at least didn't notice it).

I interpreted that recycler view work perfectly fine for you. Then instead of trying to redo same thing in gridview simply use `LayoutManager` to convert recycler view as [grid or list](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html).

Comment: Yes I used the GridLayoutManager to get a similar display. The thing is I must populate the RecyclerView "dynamically" (I don't know the type of the View to display when I start to render the list), so at first glance I thought it would not be possible to use a RecyclerView. But I figured out how to do it and just forget about the GridView. 
So yeah, a possible solution for this problem would be to use a RecyclerView instead of a ListView/GridView.

Comment: Plus Recyclerview is recommended over ListView/GridView. If that solved your problem we can close this thread .